# Earliest use of "rookie"?

Tags: etymology

What is the earliest use of the noun "rookie" and why has it become the most common synonym for newcomer? What were its vectors?

Comment: What has your research already shown?

Comment: @JasonBassford ... that dictionaries can't be trusted and that specialists will find any obscure old quote for these sweet reputation points, beating the dictionaries by a punch.

Comment: @vectory But question askers waste everyones' time if they don't at least give a baseline date from the dictionaries they consulted.

Comment: True. Everyone's time could be better spent in other pursuits.

Answer (score 5):

A simple search of **rookie** from [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=rookie)

> Barrère ["A Dictionary of Slang, Jargon & Cant," 1890] has "**Rookey**
>   (army), a recruit; from the black coat some of them wear," so perhaps
>   directly from rook (n.1). Came into general use in American English
>   during the Spanish-American War.
>
> The rapid growth of a word from a single seed transplanted in a congenial soil is one of the curiosities of literature [your question of 'vector']
>    Take a single
>   instance. A few weeks ago there was not one American soldier in a
>   thousand who knew there was such a word as "rookey." To-day there are
>   few soldiers and ex-soldiers who have not substituted it for "raw
>   recruit." ["The Midland Monthly," December 1898]

From the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167289?redirectedFrom=rookie#eid)

> 1868 Colburn's United Service Mag.    We..rather disliked the other
>   things being done away with, fancying..that they would say it was a
>   lot of raw **rookies** who could not be trusted either to draw a sword or
>   spur a horse.

Comment: Good. But the following excerpt from your  quoted passage  is my primary interest. "the rapid growth of a word from a single seed transplanted in a congenial soil is one of the curiosities of literature. " What can you advance to explain the rapid spread of this particular word? What were the vectors of the "rookie" epidemic?

Comment: @Zan700 Why does *any* word become popular and make its way into the English lexicon?

Comment: Well, that's an answer.

Comment: Addition ... rook (n,1) is a species of Eurasian crow.  This is perhaps less well known today in the US than it was at the time of the Spanish-American war?

Comment: There was a 1970's TV series "The Rookies". That's the kind of thing that can make a word popular. Was the Mafia sense of "godfather" well known before the book and movies?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that was the approach I was hoping to elicit. For example, in 2007 I started hearing the word shenanigans on cable TV and other media. It was a word that I rarely heard previously. Why were all the CNN anchors and guests using it? And then I saw  Juno with Ellen Page (2007), I heard the actress say, "I'm already pregnant, so what other kind of shenanigans can I get into?" Shenanigans was off and running. I think that's a reasonable explanation for godfather's lost innocence.

Comment: "Shenanigans" was a TV game show in the 60's. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenanigans_(game_show)

Comment: I would bet that whoever wrote the script for Juno was familiar with that game show. Did it have a long run?

Answer (score 2):

***[Rookie](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/3cu5oqi)***

> [? SE recruit or children’s use rookie, a lookout, if one considers that a lookout would be the least active &
>   ***and thus newest/youngest member of a gang***; note crow-boy, a lookout, used in Southwark in the late 19C and derived f. the rural term for the boy who scared birds away from growing crops]
>
> - ***c.1880***        ‘O’Reilly’ [US army poem] *He drank with all the rookies, and shoved his face as well, / The whole outfit is on the bum, / O’Reilly’s gone to Hell.*

From *Green’s Dictionary of Slang*